# SVELTE : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile'

Tags: javascript, promise, svelte

I am using Svelte for one week and after authenticating on my app with cidaas-sdk, the profile data is not displayed after a few seconds. The page is stuck on "... waiting", and this error in the console `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile' of undefined at Array.create_if_block$1 at create_then_block$2`

The problem here is that I have to refresh the page to show the datas.

My problem is i can't fetch `{userInfo.profile.given_name}` directly after log-in, so it's useless to reload the page to display the datas.
But when the page is reloaded, everything is OK, no error messages in the console.

```
import cidaas from './helpers/cidaas';
import Profile from './components/profile.svelte';
import { onMount } from 'svelte';
export let title;

$ : isAuth = false;
$ : isLoaded = false;

let promiseHome = Promise.resolve([]);

onMount(async () => {
    promiseHome = cidaas.getUserInfo();
        promiseHome.then(userInfo => {
        
    if(!userInfo) {
        // if you are logged
        if (window.location.href.includes("grant_type=login")) {
            cidaas.loginCallback();
            window.history.replaceState("", "", "/");
            isAuth = true;
            isLoaded = true;
            return;
        }

    }
  isAuth = !!userInfo;
  isLoaded = true;
  return;               
  })        
});
```

HTML part :

```
{#await promiseHome}
    <div class="mt-5">...Waiting</div>
{:then userInfo} 
    {#if isAuth == true}


    <div class="jumbotron col-md-8 mx-auto">
        
    <div class="hello mt-5 mb-3">Hello {userInfo.profile.given_name}!</div>
    <p>isAuth : {isAuth}</p>
    <p>isLoaded : {isLoaded}</p>
    </div> 
    <Profile/>

    
        {:else}
        <h1 class="mt-5">Bienvenue sur {title}</h1>
        <p>isAuth : {isAuth}</p>
        <p>isLoaded : {isLoaded}</p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-mdir" on:click={loginTo}>Se connecter</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-mdir" on:click={register}>S'inscrire</button>
    
    {/if}
        {:catch error}
        <p>{error.message}</p>
{/await}
```

Comment: Are you able to make a minimal reproduction in the [Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl)? I'm not sure what `cidaas.getUserInfo()` returns.

Answer (score 1):

I am not into Svelte, but after having a first look at your description - can you check the implementation of your `cidaas.loginCallback()` method. It's a Promise method and requires an `await`. Might be a reason, first time it's not working and after refreshing it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is useless:

```js
$: isAuth = false;
```

Reactive blocks are recomputed when any variable they contain changes, but a variable doesn't need to be declared in a reactive block to be reactive.

Any top-level `let` variable is reactive.

```html
<script>
  let a   // reactive
  const b = 0 // not reactive
  {
    let c // not reactive
  }
  function foo() {
    let d // not reactive
  }
</script>
```

So, just `let isAuth = false` will suffice, and still be reactive (and save Svelte some work, 'cause reactive blocks are more complex machinery than just tracking a single variable).

Now, to your problem...

The crash happens in your `then` block when the promise resolves to `undefined`, on this: `userInfo.profile.given_name`.

I don't get the whole of your loading logic so, if I had to fix this code right now, I would replace this:

```html
{:then userInfo} 
    {#if isAuth == true}
```

with this:

```html
{:then userInfo} 
    {#if userInfo && isAuth == true}
```

Answer (score 0):

My app is now working with :

```
<script>
import cidaas from './helpers/cidaas';
import Profile from './components/profile.svelte';
import { onMount } from 'svelte';

export let title;

let state = {
    isAuth: false,
    isLoaded: false,
    sUserProfile: {}
}

onMount(async () => {   
        
    cidaas.getUserInfo()
        .then(userInfo => {
                
            if(!userInfo) {
                // if you are logged out
                if (!window.location.href.includes("grant_type") && window.location.href.includes("state")) {
                    cidaas.logoutCallback();
                    window.history.replaceState("", "", "/");
                    state.isAuth = false;
                }
                // if you are logged
                if (window.location.href.includes("grant_type=login")) {
                    cidaas.loginCallback()
                        .then(response => {
                            state.sUserProfile = response.profile;          
                            state.isAuth = true;
                            window.history.replaceState("", "", "/");
                        });
                }
            } else {
                state.sUserProfile = userInfo.profile;
                state.isAuth = true
            }

            state.isLoaded = true;      
    })
}); 


function logout() {
    cidaas.logout();
}

function loginTo() {
    cidaas.loginWithBrowser();
}

function register() {
    cidaas.registerWithBrowser();
}

</script>
```

HTML :

```
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand text-white" href="http://localhost:5000"><img class="logo" src="mdir-white.png" alt="mdir_logo"></a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                
            </ul>
            {#if state.isAuth == true}
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><button class="btn btn-primary btn-mdir" on:click={logout}>Logout</button></li>
            </ul>
            {/if}
        </div>
      </nav>
</header>
 

<main>
    {#if state.isLoaded}
        {#if !state.isAuth}
            <h1 class="mt-5">Bienvenue sur {title}</h1>
            <p>isAuth : {state.isAuth}</p>
            <p>isLoaded : {state.isLoaded}</p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-mdir" on:click={loginTo}>Se connecter</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-mdir" on:click={register}>S'inscrire</button>

        {:else}
        
            <div class="jumbotron col-md-8 mx-auto">
                            
                <div class="hello mt-5 mb-3">Hello {state.sUserProfile.given_name}!</div>
                <p>isAuth : {state.isAuth}</p>
                <p>isLoaded : {state.isLoaded}</p>
            </div> 
            <Profile/>
        {/if}
        
    {:else}
        <div>...PROBLEM AUTH</div>
    {/if}
</main>
```